# Magento 2 stock inventory is not being updated

Tags: magento2, orders, inventory, quantity

when I placed order in front-end or back-end,

quantities of product is **not getting reduced or decremented**

When i have checked in admin panel...

Please help me out..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check below settings.

**Admin > Store > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Stock option > Decrease Stock When Order is Placed** Set it to yes.

If you have a multi-website or multi-store then change the same setting for all store.

Comment: I have checked  Admin > Store > Configuration > Catalog > Stock option > Decrease Stock When Order is Placed Set it to yes. but also my quantity is not getting reduced Tirth Patel

Comment: have you get any error while checkout?

Comment: No order is getting placed fine but quantity not getting reduced.. Chirag Patel

Comment: Have you checked in database? it might be possible qty is decrease in database but not update in front or backend.

Comment: Decrease product qty 0 and save product, and check product is showing out of stock?

Comment: Decrease product qty 0 and save product, and check product is showing out of stock yeah its working fine and which table name should i check to quantity is getting reduced..

Comment: Check in `cataloginventory_stock_item`

Comment: Also you can check programically https://www.mageplaza.com/how-get-product-stock-information-magento-2.html

Comment: As i followed your above instructions but do not know why quantity not getting reduced. Chirag Patel

Comment: In setup:di:compile have you get any error?

Comment: Getting some error in additional extension.. Chirag Patel

Comment: Try to solve error it might be problem :)

Comment: Hi Chirag Patel. Can you help me this proplem ?

Answer (score 6):

check your stock setting in admin panel
**Advance Inventory->manage stock** set to **yes** if you want to reduce quantity

Comment: I have checked stores->config->inventory->manage stock set to yes but also my quantity is not getting reduced Tirth Patel

Comment: check in product setting

Comment: Yeah i have checked but quantity not getting reduced..Tirth Patel

Answer (score 2):

It seems you guys have been working on 2.3.0, where the default QTY will be reduced upon shipment.

M2.3.0 has released a feature know as Salable QTY which will be reduced upon placing an order.

Answer (score 0):

QTY of product will updated after create Shipment for Order.