# Magento 2.3 update quantity not working in Arabic store view

Tags: magento2.3, arabic

Update quantity not working in Arabic store view.
While I am updating the quantity like 2 in the minicart it is updated as 1 qty

Comment: Have you tried this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/244232/magento-2-stock-inventory-is-not-being-updated

Comment: Not related to stock, while I am updating the quantity like 2 in the minicart its updated as 1 qty.